# Custom attached properties in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm creating a custom QML component (a specialization of `ListView` that allows multiple selection). I'd like to provide attached properties to objects provided to my component. I see how to [create attached properties using C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#providing-attached-objects-for-data-annotations). However, I cannot find information on adding custom properties in pure QML. Is this possible using QML?

Comment: Someone has to find a quote from a doc. AFAIK there is no QML syntax for that.

Comment: I think it's only possible from C++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is this possible using QML?

No.

Comment: Thanks for the authoritative answer.

Comment: Oh, and it might be nice to mention this in documentation somewhere in [this section](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attached-properties-and-attached-signal-handlers).

Answer (score 7):

There is an alternative, easy and clean way to this in QML - just use an adapter object that implements the desired properties. Then instead of attaching just nest into the adapter - use it as as a parent / container. You can also nest objects into the adapter, getting another C++ exclusive - grouped properties. A possible way to minimize the overhead of this is to use JS objects and properties, with a downside - no change notifications, which you can somewhat mitigate by emitting manually.

An example:

```
// Adapter.qml - interface with attached properties
Item {
  id: adapter
  property int customInt : Math.random() * 1000
  property var group : {"a" : Math.random(), "b" : Math.random() }
  default property Component delegate
  width: childrenRect.width
  height: childrenRect.height
  Component.onCompleted: delegate.createObject(adapter)
}

// usage
ListView {
  width: 100
  height: 300
  model: 5
  delegate: Adapter {
    Row {
      spacing: 10
      Text { text: index }
      Text { text: customInt }
      Text { text: group.a }
      Text { text: group.a }
    }
  }
}
```

It is fairly painless and convenient compared to some other QML workarounds. You don't even have to do `parent.parent.customInt` - the properties are directly accessible as if they are attached, this works because of dynamic scoping. The `default property` allows to avoid setting the inner delegate as a property you just nest the delegate you want directly in the adapter.

In many cases those acrobatics are overkill, you can just wrap in place:

```
ListView {
  width: 100
  height: 300
  model: 5
  delegate: Item {
    width: childrenRect.width
    height: childrenRect.height
    property string custom1: "another"
    property string custom2: "set of"
    property string custom3: "properties"
    Row {
      spacing: 10
      Text { text: index }
      Text { text: custom1 }
      Text { text: custom2 }
      Text { text: custom3 }
    }
  }
}
```

The only key part really is the binding for the size of the adapter object so that the view can properly layout the objects. I routinely use a `Wrap` element which essentially does the same but is implemented in C++, which is much more efficient than a QML binding.

Comment: Can you provide an example illustrating what you suggest? I'm having trouble picturing it.

Comment: @Phrogz there you go